# After Calendar set. Cant get timeinMillis()

Tags: android, time, calendar, android-alarms

So I'm trying to make an `AlarmManager` that's suppose to launch at a specific time. The problem is that when I set the time, tt doesn't work. I think the main problem is that after I have change the time on `Calendar`, in logs object value "time" shows ?

```
timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(timeOff);
timeOff.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
System.out.println(timeOff);
System.out.println("TIME:: "+timeOff.getTimeInMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(TabsActivity.this, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TabsActivity.this, 1122, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(am.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(),timeOff.getTimeInMillis()+ 1000,pendingIntent);// + 604800000L,pendingIntent);
```

Logs shows this:
Before change:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1406899765159,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Riga,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=31,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=213,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=29,SECOND=25,MILLISECOND=159,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

After Change:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Riga,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=32,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=219,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=30,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=159,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

As you see the value -

```
Time=?
```

So my question, what am I doing wrong, why does after I have set the time, it doesn't show. And even if I try to log out plain `timeOff.getTimeInMillis()` , it doesn't show anything at all.

---

### Solution

Change `timeOff.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY)` to `timeOff.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY)`

Comment: `timeOff.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);` wouldn't it be set or roll instead of add?

Comment: now i feel so stupid -.- thank you mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since calendar.add() method is abstract , you can use like this

```
        Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(timeOff);
        timeOff.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
        timeOff.getTime()
        //System.out.println(timeOff.getTime());
        timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        System.out.println(timeOff);
        System.out.println("TIME:: "+timeOff.getTimeInMillis());
```